# FCM push notification only receive once after upload to testFlight

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, testflight

i am using FCM to push notification for my project. And all worked fine when the App was installed with XCode. I can receive push notification. 
After i upload my App into testFlight. Then the push notification can only push once. After that, i cannot receive any message anymore.
Below is my code in AppDelegate.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Definition.h"
#import "Message.h"

// FCM
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above. Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for
// devices running iOS 10 and above.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    // ------------------------------------------------------
    // FCM Setting
    // ------------------------------------------------------

    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.


#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
             completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             }
             ];

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];


    return YES;
}

// FCM
// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    [self pushNotificationAction:userInfo sender:@"ID1(bgtap)"];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    [self pushNotificationAction:userInfo sender:@"ID2(bgtap)"];

}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    [self pushNotificationAction:userInfo sender:@"ID3"];


}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

    [self pushNotificationAction:userInfo sender:@"ID4"];

}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message

    [self pushNotificationAction:[remoteMessage appData] sender:@"fcm"];

}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.


    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
    if(![refreshedToken isEqualToString:@""]){
        [Utility setValue:refreshedToken key:@"fcmtoken"];
        [self connectToFcm];
    }
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
#pragma mark - Push notification action
- (void) pushNotificationAction:(NSDictionary *)userInfo sender:(NSString *)sender {

    // Log
    NSString *logMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",sender,userInfo];
    NSLog(@"%@",logMessage);
    // FCM type
    NSString *tag = [userInfo valueForKey:@"sync"];
    NSLog(@"FCM type=%@",tag);
    // type snyc
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTableM3" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
    if([tag isEqualToString:@"all"] || YES){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTableM3" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    // type other
    if(tag == nil){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTableM1" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:userInfo, nil];

        if([test count]>0){
            Message *message = [[Message alloc] init];
            [message insert:message];
        }
    }

}


// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
    // token 存進去
    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    [Utility setValue:test key:@"pushtoken"];

    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    if(![refreshedToken isEqualToString:@""]){
        [Utility setValue:refreshedToken key:@"fcmtoken"];
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown];
    }
    NSLog(@"FCMs toke %@",refreshedToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // for development
    //[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    // for production
    //[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];


    [self connectToFcm];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    //NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
    NSLog(@"Move to Background");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]
// FCM結束

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}



- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown` for Sandbox(Development) - `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox` and for Adhoc,testFlight and App Store use following - `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd`   try if problem is not solved then ask me

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. I still only receive push notification once.